# Apply Visual Style in vc++ application

Tags: visual-c++, skin, visual-styles

I already have a vc++ application buyt it look of a bit old version.

Now I want to apply visual style in that application. Can anybody tell me how to go about that as I did that in my c# application with the help of [VisualStyler.Net](http://www.skin-soft.co.uk/products/visualstyler/overview.aspx)

But I don't know how to use that in vc++.

Comment: How about [SetWindowTheme function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759827%28VS.85%29.aspx)? I haven't tried this in VC++ before though :)

Comment: There is also an article called [Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)